# SQL IN Operator with Select

Tags: sql

I want to use the IN Operator in SQL with a select statement but I get the following error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

The code that I am using looks as follows:

```
select * from Table where ID in (select Units from Table2)
```

Comment: You mean `where` ID in () ?

Comment: What your inner query returns ?

Comment: @Noob Unchained It returns a list of numbers. I think the IN operator is looking for a list like 1,2,3

Answer (score 4):

You have use `WHEN` instead of `WHERE`

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `ID` IN (SELECT `Units` FROM `Table2`)
```

Comment: xylar, that was a typo on my part. I think that the second select statement is not in a format that the "IN" operator can use

Comment: @user1966593 what does `select Units from Table2` return? Are you using any aggregate functions such as `SUM` or `COUNT`, in your sub-query?

Comment: 'select Units from Table2' returns a list of numbers which link to the ID. Is the problem that the list return is not comma separated?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `where` in place of `when` in your query. The correct query will be:

```
select * from Table where ID in (select Units from Table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to select specific ID columns in your second query, something like this:

```
Select*from Table where ID IN (Select ID from Table2)
```